# Terraform azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group not creating nat_rule collection

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have nat_rule_collection defined at the bottom of this resource. Everything is created except that nat_rule_collection.  Is there any mistake here that could cause this?  I redacted the real destination address, but the real one one does match the public load balancer IP.

I know that the group indicates egress but I am just trying it there, and I believe that is just a label.

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "policy" {
  name               = "AksEgressPolicyRuleCollectionGroup"
  firewall_policy_id = azurerm_firewall_policy.policy.id
  priority           = 500

  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "ApplicationRules"
    priority = 500
    action   = "Allow"

    rule {
      name             = "AllowMicrosoftFqdns"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "*.cdn.mscr.io",
        "mcr.microsoft.com",
        "*.data.mcr.microsoft.com",
        "management.azure.com",
        "login.microsoftonline.com",
        "acs-mirror.azureedge.net",
        "dc.services.visualstudio.com",
        "*.opinsights.azure.com",
        "*.oms.opinsights.azure.com",
        "*.microsoftonline.com",
        "*.monitoring.azure.com",
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }

    rule {
      name             = "AllowFqdnsForOsUpdates"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "download.opensuse.org",
        "security.ubuntu.com",
        "ntp.ubuntu.com",
        "packages.microsoft.com",
        "snapcraft.io"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }
    
    rule {
      name             = "AllowImagesFqdns"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "auth.docker.io",
        "registry-1.docker.io",
        "production.cloudflare.docker.com"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }

    rule {
      name             = "AllowBing"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "*.bing.com"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }

    rule {
      name             = "AllowGoogle"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      destination_fqdns = [
        "*.google.com"
      ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }


    rule {
      name             = "AllowPublicPOrt80"
      source_addresses = ["*"]

      # destination_fqdns = [
      #   "*.google.com"
      # ]

      protocols {
        port = "80"
        type = "Http"
      }

      protocols {
        port = "443"
        type = "Https"
      }
    }



  }

  network_rule_collection {
    name     = "NetworkRules"
    priority = 400
    action   = "Allow"

    rule {
      name                  = "Time"
      source_addresses      = ["*"]
      destination_ports     = ["123"]
      destination_addresses = ["*"]
      protocols             = ["UDP"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "DNS"
      source_addresses      = ["*"]
      destination_ports     = ["53"]
      destination_addresses = ["*"]
      protocols             = ["UDP"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "ServiceTags"
      source_addresses      = ["*"]
      destination_ports     = ["*"]
      destination_addresses = [
        "AzureContainerRegistry",
        "MicrosoftContainerRegistry",
        "AzureActiveDirectory"
      ]
      protocols             = ["Any"]
    }

    rule {
      name                  = "Internet"
      source_addresses      = ["*"]
      destination_ports     = ["*"]
      destination_addresses = ["*"]
      protocols             = ["TCP"]
    }
  }



  nat_rule_collection {
    name     = "nat_rule_collection1"
    priority = 100
    action   = "Dnat"
    rule {
      name                = "fw-public-web-port-80"
      protocols           = ["TCP"]
      source_addresses    = ["*"]
      destination_address = "123.123.123.123"
      destination_ports   = ["80"]
      translated_address  = "10.9.0.1"
      translated_port     = "80"
    }
  }




  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      application_rule_collection,
      network_rule_collection,
      nat_rule_collection
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you create it once already and made changes and then wanted to reapply?

Comment: I did add nat_rule_collection after the other resources were applied

Comment: My guess is that the `lifecycle` rule is stopping it from being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ignore_changes (list of attribute names)*** - By default, Terraform detects any difference in the current settings of a real infrastructure object and plans to update the remote object to match configuration.

**The ignore_changes feature is intended to be used when a resource is created with references to `data` that may change in the future**,**but should not affect said resource after its creation.**
So you applying `natrule` code after other two rule created. Ingnore_changes meta-argument specifies resource attributes that Terraform should ignore when planning updates to the associated remote object so this might be stopping you to create the natrule

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ ]
}
```

For more information you can refer this [***Terraform Document***](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle)